# How can i generate the english words from given characters in python

Tags: python, django

In my django application the user will enter some characters in the text box
and based on the characters i need to supply the common words from english dictionary and suggest that to the user.

Is  ther any common english dictionary database available or some sort of api from any other site which can accomplish the task

Comment: /usr/share/dict/
/var/lib/dict/

Comment: The problem with linux.words is that the user wants common words and some of those are questionable as common.  Also common can imply common with respect to frequency and linux.words doesn't have a frequency count.  There are English learning texts that have a kind of frequency (the top 500 or 100 or 1000 English words/nouns/verbs, etc).  But there has to be a Ziph's law distribution of English words somewhere - I know I've seen it in fact online.

Comment: SO here's a link to an English frequency list: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aFrequency_lists#English

Comment: I removed the tag spam [tag:data-mining]. There is no data mining involved in using a wordlist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a program that can find anagrams. Here is a non-django solution. It uses /usr/share/dict/words as suggested by Joel.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def canonical_form(word):
    return tuple(sorted(word))

anagrams = defaultdict(list)

for word in open("/usr/share/dict/words"):
    word = word.lower().strip()
    anagrams[canonical_form(word)].append(word)

while True:
    print anagrams[canonical_form(raw_input())]
```